# SNS trigger issue for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have SNS topic in Account A. From this SNS i want to trigger lambda in Account B.

But i am getting below error.I am trying to deploy using cloudformation stack

```
The account A is not the owner of Endpoint ARNof-lambda-in-accountB (Service: AmazonSNS,Status Code: 403,ErrorCode: Authorizationerror)
```

Things i make sure

1. SNS has access correct access policy to subscribe Lambda in Account B
2. A trigger set for Lambda in Account B for SNS in account A

Comment: Which account are you using to create the sns subscription?

Comment: @cementblocks I am using Account A,in above senario

Comment: Use account B to create the subscription. You'll need to allow it via the SNS topic policy in account A

Comment: @cementblocks You are right that was the issue. Here actually we have to create subscription in Account B even though topic is in Account A.

Comment: I've formalized this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SNS subscription must be created from the same account that the Lambda function exists in. The SNS topic policy must allow subscriptions from the Lambda's account.